Including ObjectBox Entities from an AAR Library Module in Main Android App (ObjectBox 4.0.2)
I'm encountering an issue with integrating ObjectBox entities defined in a library module (provided as an AAR file) into my main Android application.
Setup Details:

Library Module (AndroidCore):

Contains ObjectBox entities annotated with @Entity.
Compiled and distributed as an AAR file.
Uses ObjectBox version 4.0.2.
build.gradle configuration:



gradle
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.library'
        id 'io.objectbox' version '4.0.2'
    }


    dependencies {
        implementation 'io.objectbox:objectbox-android:4.0.2'
    }



Main Application (MyApp):

Includes the AndroidCore AAR library.
Uses ObjectBox version 4.0.2.
build.gradle configuration:



gradle
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'io.objectbox' version '4.0.2'
    }


    dependencies {
        implementation 'io.objectbox:objectbox-android:4.0.2'
        implementation files('libs/AndroidCore.aar') // Path to the AAR file
    }


Problem Description:
When I include the AndroidCore AAR into my main application MyApp, the ObjectBox entities defined in AndroidCore are not recognized in MyApp. Specifically:

The default.json model file in MyApp is not generated with the entities from AndroidCore.
Methods like .entityClasses() or .entity() on MyObjectBox.builder() either don't exist or require parameters that are incompatible (e.g., they expect EntityInfo instead of a Class).

What I've Tried:

Ensured Entities Are Public and Annotated:

All entities in AndroidCore are public and properly annotated with @Entity.


Matching ObjectBox Versions:

Both AndroidCore and MyApp use the same ObjectBox version (4.0.2).


Configuring objectbox Extension:

Tried to configure the objectbox extension in MyApp's build.gradle to include model files or packages from AndroidCore:
objectbox {
    includes = ['com.mycompany.androidcore']
}


However, this results in an error:
Could not set unknown property 'includes' for extension 'objectbox' of type io.objectbox.gradle.ObjectBoxPluginExtension.






Exploring Alternative Methods:

Looked for updated ways to include external entities as per the latest ObjectBox documentation but couldn't find a solution that works with AAR modules.



Questions:

How can I correctly include ObjectBox entities from an AAR library module (AndroidCore) into my main application (MyApp) using ObjectBox version 4.0.2?

Is there a specific configuration required in the build.gradle files of both modules to enable ObjectBox to recognize and merge entities from an external AAR module?

Are there updated methods or best practices for this scenario in ObjectBox 4.0.2, considering that properties like includes or modelFiles seem to be deprecated or no longer supported?


Additional Information:

Constraints:

For project structure reasons, I need to keep AndroidCore as an AAR library rather than including it as a module in the same project.


Errors Encountered:

Build errors related to unknown properties in the objectbox extension.
The main application does not recognize entities from the AAR library, leading to runtime errors when accessing the database.



Request:
Any guidance on how to properly include and use ObjectBox entities from an AAR library module in my main application would be greatly appreciated. If someone has a working example or can point me toward relevant documentation or best practices for ObjectBox version 4.0.2, that would be very helpful.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I resolved it on my own. I’m sharing the solution here in case someone else needs it in the future.
The issue was caused by the fact that during the initialization of the store object:
MyObjectBox.builder()
  .androidContext(context)
  .build();

the database name was not specified. Since I had to perform two initializations—one in the main App and one for the entities managed in the AAR—having the MyObjectBox initialized without specifying a database name confused the ObjectBox manager.
It was sufficient to declare the database name for each initialization, and both ObjectBox instances became usable without issues in the main App.
In the main app:
public class ObjectBox {
    private static BoxStore store;

    public static void init(Context context) {
        store = MyObjectBox.builder()
                .androidContext(context)
                .name("mainapp-db")
                .build();
    }

    public static BoxStore get() { return store; }
}

in AAR:
public class ObjectBox {
    private static BoxStore store;

    public static void init(Context context) {
        store = MyObjectBox.builder()
                .androidContext(context)
                .name("androidcore-db")
                .build();
    }

    public static BoxStore get() { return store; }
}

